# define a function within a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2 {
    ...
    int myfunc(void)
      {
         return 1;
      }
    class myclass {
      ..
    };
  }
}
```

I thought it is possible to define a function this way, and access it both from 'myclass' and its derivatives. However gcc doesn't even want to compile this code:

```
multiple definition of `n1::n2::myfunc()'
```

This function is the only one here, what am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a header file? If so, it will get defined in every .cpp file that includes it. You should make a declaration in the .h file and a definition in one specific .cpp file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to either mark the function `inline` to avoid breaking the one definition rule, or place the implementation in a `.cpp` file, and leave only the declaration in the header.